# How to remove time from Calender.js

Tags: javascript, calendar

I am using calender.js want to remove time from calender component.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        Calendar.setup( {
            inputField : "ToDt", // id of the input field 
            ifFormat : "%m/%d/%Y ", // format of the input field 
            button : "ToDtButton", // trigger for the calendar (button ID)
            align : "Br", // alignment (defaults to "Bl")
            singleClick :true,
            showsTime :true,
             timeFormat :12 
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Javascript != Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
showsTime :false,
```

This removes time from calener